# Python Port Scanner

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, socket

This is only my third Python script.  Be brutal with me.  Any tips, tricks, best practices, or better usages would be great!

```
import socket
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

THREADS = 512
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1

def ping(host, port, results = None):
    try:
        socket.socket().connect((host, port))
        if results is not None:
            results.append(port)
        print(str(port) + " Open")
        return True
    except:
        return False

def scan_ports(host):
    available_ports = []
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = THREADS) as executor:
        print("\nScanning ports on " + host + " ...")
        for port in range(1, 65535):
            executor.submit(ping, host, port, available_ports)
    print("\nDone.")
    available_ports.sort()
    print(str(len(available_ports)) + " ports available.")
    print(available_ports)

def main():
    scan_ports("127.0.0.1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: @GarethRees Just learning from a book.  If I were being malicious, I certainly wouldn't post the question under my real name.  Haha

Comment: [Follow up question here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46842/python-port-scanner-2-0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not Pythonic to pass in a mutable object and use that to store results (like it is in C).

`range(start, stop)` is not inclusive of stop, so you have an off by one error as well.

Using a catch-all `except` line is also poor practice. It's important to catch expected exceptions and reraise the rest.

Also Python lists are thread safe only because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) in CPython. This code would not be thread safe in other implementations such as Jython. Notice how your version always reports open ports in ascending order.

Threads are fine for IO bounded actions, but since pinging localhost is so fast GIL contention slows down performance in this case. Your implementation ran in 27 seconds on my laptop.

By comparison, my implementation ran in 2.76 seconds. Replacing `map()` with `pool.map()` led to a runtime of 1.38 seconds:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from errno import ECONNREFUSED
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket

NUM_CORES = 4


def ping(host, port):
    try:
        socket.socket().connect((host, port))
        print(str(port) + " Open")
        return port
    except socket.error as err:
        if err.errno == ECONNREFUSED:
            return False
        raise


def scan_ports(host):
    p = Pool(NUM_CORES)
    ping_host = partial(ping, host)
    return filter(bool, p.map(ping_host, range(1, 65536)))


def main(host=None):
    if host is None:
        host = "127.0.0.1"

    print("\nScanning ports on " + host + " ...")
    ports = list(scan_ports(host))
    print("\nDone.")

    print(str(len(ports)) + " ports available.")
    print(ports)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Wow.  Amazing performance difference!  Thanks for all your comments.  I've got some Googling to do to completely figure out how your code works, but this will definitely help me learn the language better.

Comment: Can you explain your usage of the `filter()` function?  I don't get why your first argument is `bool`.  It seems like the function is supposed to take another function as the first argument, or `None` to just purge `False` (which seems like what you're trying to do).  Would passing in `None` have worked just as well?

Comment: Interestingly, your version actually runs a lot slower on my PC.  The performance benefits may only be on *nix.

Comment: Forking is cheap on *nix, expensive on Windows. Vice versa for threads. Also make sure `NUM_CORES` accurately reflects how many physical cores on the machine.

Comment: From `map(ping_host(range(1, 65536)))` we get an example list `[False, 2, False, 4, ...]`. `filter(bool, list)` will apply `bool()` to each element in the list and only keep those that evaluate to `True`. `None`, `False`, `0`, `[]`, `''` evaluates to `False`, everything else evaluates to `True`. Thus `filter(bool, [None, 2, False, 4])` results in the list `[2, 4]`.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from wting's answer I'd add that you call `main()` and then `scan_ports()` when you could've called `scan_ports` directly in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: It's preferable that Jeff calls `main()` and implements logic within that function. This allows for better use at the interpreter (`from scan import main`) and unit testing. Guido goes into this a bit more: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829