# Python Port Scanner 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, concurrency

A few months ago I put up a [port scanner for review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/python-port-scanner).  Now, I've updated it with some new Python knowledge and integraing the feedback I got.

Some things I specifically think might be wrong with it or feel clunky to me:

1. Default argument values for the `scan_ports` function.  I set the default values, but then I have to check for `None` again when I enter the block.  I was actually kind of surprised and disappointed that, if the arg was `None`, it didn't just automatically take the default.  Any better way to handle this?
2. The `is_address_valid` function.  I'm not entirely sure I did this the proper way, with catching multiple exception types.  Not sure if I'm catching things I shouldn't be, or if there's a more elegant way to approach it.
3. Detecting the operating system.  Not sure if the standard is to use `os.name` or `platform.system()`.
4. When is it acceptable to actually add line-breaks into your function bodies?  Most of the scripts I've seen are really, really loathe to do so, and I kind of get it since everything in Python is space-based instead of bracket-based.  But sometimes the function bodies seem to be a bit too long and it starts to look bad.
5. (More of a StackOverflow question, but still, if someone wants to throw it in as a tidbit...) Why do the arguments in `socket.socket().connect((host, 80))` have to be wrapped in another set of parentheses?  Found that this was the way to do it, but couldn't find in the API *why* it has to be that way.

Any tips or feedback are greatly appreciated!

Also, I think @GarethRees was skeptical in the other question that I might be using this for malicious purposes.  I'm actually just learning from a book called [Violent Python](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597499579), and a port scanner is the first thing it goes over in the book.  The book is a bit more interesting than a normal textbook that goes over different variations of "Hello World!", haha.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import errno
import functools
import multiprocessing
import os
import platform
import socket
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

DEFAULT_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 2
DEFAULT_CORES = 4
DEFAULT_THREADS = 512
PORT_RANGE = range(1, 65536)

def ping(host, port):
    try:
        socket.socket().connect((host, port))
        print(str(port) + " Open")
        return port
    except socket.timeout:
        return False
    except socket.error as socket_error:
        if socket_error.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
            return False
        raise

def thread_scan(host, threads):
    print('Scanning ' + host + ' with threads ...')
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = threads) as executor:
        ping_partial = functools.partial(ping, host)
        return list(filter(bool, executor.map(ping_partial, PORT_RANGE)))

def fork_scan(host, cores):
    print('Scanning ' + host + ' with forks ...')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
    ping_partial = functools.partial(ping, host)
    return list(filter(bool, pool.map(ping_partial, PORT_RANGE)))

def is_address_valid(host):
    try:
        socket.socket().connect((host, 80))
        return True
    except socket.gaierror:
        return False
    except (socket.timeout, socket.error):
        return True

def get_os_info():
    return os.name + ' [' + platform.system() + ' ' + platform.version() + ']'

def scan_ports(host = DEFAULT_HOST,
               timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
               threads = DEFAULT_THREADS,
               cores = DEFAULT_CORES):
    if host is None:
        host = DEFAULT_HOST
    if timeout is None:
        timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
    if threads is None:
        threads = DEFAULT_THREADS
    if cores is None:
        cores = DEFAULT_CORES
    available_ports = []
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
    if not is_address_valid(host):
        print('DNS lookup for \'' + host + '\' failed.')
        return
    if os.name == 'nt':
        print('Windows OS detected.')
        available_ports = thread_scan(host, threads)
    elif os.name == 'posix':
        print('*Nix OS detected.')
        available_ports = fork_scan(host, cores)
    else:
        print('Unidentified operating system: ' + get_os_info())
        available_ports = fork_scan(host, cores)
    print('Done.')
    available_ports.sort()
    print()
    print(str(len(available_ports)) + ' ports available.')
    print(available_ports)

def main():
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument('-ip', '--host', help = 'IP address/host to scan')
    arg_parser.add_argument('-to', '--timeout', help = 'Connection timeout in seconds', type = int)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-t', '--threads', help = 'Maximum number of threads to spawn (Windows only)', type = int)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-c', '--cores', help = 'Number of cores to utilize (*Nix only)', type = int)
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    scan_ports(args.host, args.timeout, args.threads, args.cores)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [Follow-up question here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46866/9357)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're opening a lot of sockets but not closing them.  Those are likely file descriptor leaks.  (Whether or not it actually leaks depends on the garbage collector's behaviour.)

If you're using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` for the multithreaded version, then you should also use [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) for the multiprocess version.

`ping` usually implies an ICMP echo.  If you're actually doing a TCP scan, call it `tcp_ping` or something.

The status messages are misleading.  "Windows OS detected" sounds like you performed [OS fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting) on the remote peer, but you actually mean that the port scanner is running on a Windows host.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  How does one close the socket appropriately?

Comment: I guess just storing the reference to `socket.socket()` and then calling `.close()` on it later.  Thanks.  I'll try it.

Comment: Actually, you should [prefer Python's `with` construct](//stackoverflow.com/q/1369526) if you can.